# Translation of "this much and no more"

Tags: grammar, translation, sentence-structure

I found this sentence and its English translation on [tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/402894):

> 我知道的就這麼多了。
>
> Beyond this I know nothing.

Now I'm trying to parse the sentence structure, and I'd like some confirmation or a correction, please. I think that 我知道的 means "what I know" or "the things that I know". Then 就這麼多了 means "just this much". So I might literally translate the sentence as, "What I know is just this much, and no more."

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are close.

Basically:

知道 = to know

我知道 = I know

我知道的 = What I know

就 = Just

這麼多 = this much

就這麼多了 = Just this much

I personally wouldn't translate this as "Beyond this I know nothing." It would be closer to "What I know is just this much", however I would translate it as "I only know this much". I don't see where this sentence would insinuate the "and no more" or the "beyond this"; it is not expressed in the sentence.

It's the type of sentence that would benefit from a bit more context to get a more accurate translation.

Answer (score 4):

without over-thinking, it translates to: This is all I know.

maybe i watch too many detective movies, in which the guilty will end their confessions w/ "我知道的就這麼多了"...which to me translates to "this is all I know" in english dialog in such settings.

Comment: Nice example of usage.